# undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I display an array of hours in a dropdown field

```
[["09:30am", "2013-02-14 09:30:00"], ["10:00am", "2013-02-14 10:00:00"] ...
```

I render the array with:

```
<%= f.select :atime, @time_options %>
```

I assign the values of the array to the instance variable in the controller

```
  def new
    @time_options = Appointment.time_options
    @doctor = Doctor.find(params[:doctor_id])
    @appointment = @doctor.schedule.appointments.build

  end

  # GET /appointments/1/edit
  def edit
    @time_options = Appointment.time_options
    @doctor = Doctor.find(params[:doctor_id])
    @appointment = @doctor.appointments.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /appointments
  # POST /appointments.json
  def create
    @time_options = Appointment.time_options    
    @doctor = Doctor.find(params[:doctor_id])
    @appointment = @doctor.schedule.appointments.new(params[:appointment])


      if @appointment.save
        #send email
        AppointmentMailer.appointment_confirmation(@appointment, I18n.locale).deliver
        AppointmentMailer.new_appointment(@appointment, I18n.locale).deliver

        redirect_to :action => 'thank_you'
      else
        render action: 'new'
      end
  end
```

And in the model I have defined a class method to build the array

```
  def self.time_options
    start_of_day = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day
    start_time = start_of_day + 9.hours
    end_time = start_of_day + 17.hours

    lunch_start = start_of_day + 13.hours
    lunch_end = start_of_day + 14.hours + 30.minutes

    times = []
    until start_time > end_time
      start_time = (start_time + 30.minutes)
      unless start_time >= lunch_start && start_time < lunch_end
        times << start_time
      end
    end
    times.map{|t| [t.strftime("%I:%M%p").downcase, t.to_s(:db)] }
  end
```

However when I submit the form, i get a `undefined method`empty?' for nil:NilClass` error on:

```
<%= f.select :atime, @time_options %>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is your form rendering correctly?  It sounds like it is because you say you are submitting it.  can you post your controller code?

Comment: When you *submit* the form? That's pretty different than *rendering the form. Which is it?

Comment: When I submit the form. @DaveNewton

Comment: @ScottHelm, yes is rendering correctly.

Comment: @ScottHelm, I added the controller code.

Comment: add the whole stacktrace please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
 <%= f.select :atime, @time_options %>
```

should be like this

```
  <%= f.select :atime_id, @time_options %>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `create` method, start with the `@doctor` and go down the chain: schedule, then `params[:appointment]`, until you find the nil, then figure out why it's nil.  Rails.logger or pry if you're running rails s will be your friend.