# repeated issue, could be validations in my models? [Rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

it seems like a lot of people posted this problem  [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881876/undefined-method-empty-for-nilnilclass) but the answer there, is not my case I guess.

in my models I have

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
 validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
 validates :category_id, presence: true
end
```

and

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :project
 validates :question, presence: true
 validates :question_type, presence: true
 validates :project_id, presence: true
 QUESTIONS_TYPES = ['Single', 'Multiple', 'A text']
end
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
```

tha form:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :project_id %><br>
<%= f.select :project_id, @project_options %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :question %><br>
<%= f.text_field :question %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :question_type %><br>
<%= f.select :question_type, Question::QUESTIONS_TYPES %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The controller

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :set_projects, only: [:new, :edit]
 .
 .
 def create
  @question = Question.new(question_params)
 .
 .
 end
 .
 .
 private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_question
   @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def question_params
   params.require(:question).permit(:question, :question_type, :project_id)
  end

  def set_projects
   @project_options = Project.all.map{|p| [p.name, p.id]}
  end
end
```

The error

```
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #16):

 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :project_id %><br>
   <%= f.select :project_id, @project_options %>
 </div>
```

the post answer I mentioned before says it should be project_id in the form, but it is correct in my code. In my case the error raises only if I have some empty fields otherwise it goes well. could be something wrong with validations?

Thanks!!

Comment: whts there in line#16?
is this: `<%= f.select :project_id, @project_options %>?`

Comment: Can you post your controller code? Probably you are not assigning any value to @project_options.

Comment: I put the controller code above, actually I have the values assigning I can see them in the dropdown and if I don't leave any field empty the submit passed. (the errors shows up only if any field in the form is empty even a text_field corresponding to another attribute)

Comment: @Muntasim yes it's the corresponding line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it seems it has validation issue and could cot create/update the record.

But the error is: your `create` and `update` action probably have a else block in the controller to handle the failed cases. make sure you initiate `@project_options` there in the else block. What happens is it cant create the record hence tries to render the new/edit form directly(not executing new/edit methods so `@project_options` is not initialized). put something in your controller in create action like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @question.save
    format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else

    format.html do 
       set_projects #need to call set_projects method here.
       render action: "new" 
    end 
    format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

You should have same thing in your `update` action as well

Comment: awesome!! I spent a day looking for the solution. by the way, why this line before_action : set_projects, only:[:new, :edit] dosn't initialize the projects after rendering to new?

Comment: As I mentioned:

 What happens is it cant create the record hence tries to render the new/edit form directly(not executing new/edit methods so @project_options is not initialized)

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is that empty? method is called on nil. The two objects here are @question and @project_options. Check if you have assigned the proper values to these instance variables in your controller.